# Delete more than 50K records in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, table, delete

We have 500k records in a SQL table. Below is table structure

```
UserID varchar
FirstName varchar
LastName varchar
Address varchar
```

We need to delete 50K records in this table. We tried below approach

**Approach 1:** This has 50K DELETE statements which takes around 40 minutes

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE UserID = 'tom345'
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE UserID = 'john45'
```

and so on until 50K DELETE statements

**Approach 2:** This contains all 50K user id in IN statement but it takes more that 40 minutes

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE UserID IN ( 'tom345', 'john45',  .... )
```

Is there any other approach which takes less time comparatively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a temp table, put in your users and use that in your delete statement:

```
CREATE TABLE delete_users (user_id ... primary key);
INSERT INTO delete_users (user_id) values (...),(...)...;
DELETE FROM  [dbo].[Table] x 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM delete_users y WHERE x.user_id = y.user_id
);
DROP TABLE delete_users;
```

Comment: This is really very quick.Thank you @Lennart. Below query perfectly worked out for me

`DELETE FROM [dbo].[FIRSTTABLE]
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[SECONDTABLE] ST WHERE ST.UserID = [dbo].[FIRSTTABLE].UserID )`